# Firebase Notification by topic

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new to firebase. I want to send notification to my list of followers(group of members like instagram).

I created a unique topic for each user and all the followers of a user will subscribe to the topic. when i send a notification to the topic, notification not delivered to all followers consistently.

When User clicks **follow** button i am subscribing to the topic by

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(FollowerUserID);
```

by clicking **unfollow** i am unsubscribing the topic

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic(FollowerUserID);
```

I have used Firebase cloud functions for pushing notification to the Topic.

If Firebase Token changed for a user whether we need subscribe the topic again?

I don't know how the subscribe/unsubscribe model works. will anyone explain how its works ?

kindly help me get out of this problem.

Suggest me the best way to send notifications to group of peoples(Followers).

Answer (score 1):

First thing first.
If a firebase user token changes and that token was subscribed to a cloud messaging notification then he will no longer receive any notifications, also if he was subscribed to a topic and that topic changes he won't get any notifications from the new topic

For your business logic, I'd make a cloud messaging topic for each user and whenever someone follows that user I will subscribe that user token to the topic of the followed user.
say user X followed user Y, and user Z followed user X. both Y and Z will subscribe to topic X.

check this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Cloud Messaging topics subscribe based on **Instance ID**, *not* FCM Token. An Instance ID uniquely identifies an app device instance and does not change unless the user uninstalls the app. If an app instance is subscribed to a topic, it will remain subscribed to it. While FCM Tokens periodically refresh, this does not affect topic subscriptions. There is no need to resubscribe users every time a token refreshes. See the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) for some useful information. You can also see the [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging.html#subscribeToTopic(java.lang.String)) indicating how `subscribeToTopic` works with the Instance ID.

Comment: Thanks Jen for your answer. I have an scenario, that i have used instance id for subscribeToTopic 

if some user uninstall the application (app instance id will be removed from the topic) and install the app again (New instance id will be created but not subscibed to the topic).

How will i send a notification to new installed user from firebase cloud functions.

Is there is any possible way to send notifications via firebase cloud functions ?